# jQuery - Closing modal pop-up by clicking outside of it not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to close a pop-up when clicking outside of it.

**HTML**

```
<span class="open"data-modal="modal1">Button</span>

<div class="modal" id="modal1">

    <!--modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">

        <!--close button-->
        <span class="close">&times;</span>

        <!--content-->

    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    //open pop-up when span is clicked
    $(".open").on("click", function() {
        var modalId = $(this).data("modal");
        var $modal = $("#" + modalId);
        $modal.show();
    });

    //close pop-up when close button is clicked
    $(".close").on("click", function() {
        $(this).closest(".modal").hide();
    });



    $("body").click(function(){
        $(".modal").hide();
    });

    // Prevent events from getting pass .popup
    $(".modal-content").click(function(e){
       e.stopPropagation();
    });

});
```

At the bottom of that code block, I have a click function on the body that hides the modal, but if `modal-content` is clicked, then `e.stopPropagation();` is fired.

However, when I click the button to open the pop-up, it doesn't open because of `$("body").click(function(){}`.

Is there a way I can wrap `$("body").click(function(){}` in something like:

```
if($('.modal').show == true{ ... });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is the same you already did before, this is to stop the propagation when you click the `open` button:

```
//open pop-up when span is clicked
$(".open").on("click", function(e) { //with event now
    e.stopPropagation(); //stopping propagation here
    var modalId = $(this).data("modal");
    var $modal = $("#" + modalId);
    $modal.show();
});
```

So that it doesn't then call the `hide()` on the `body` click handler.

Comment: Wow, that did it. Does this make `$(".modal-content").click(function(e){
       e.stopPropagation();
    });` redundant?

Comment: Or are is that part still necessary?

Comment: @coffeebot No you need still need that one, otherwise when you click inside the modal it closes

Comment: Sorry, that's a dumb question

Comment: Yeah, just figured that out. Thanks.

Comment: You could combine the two though by testing if the event target is a child of the modal. If it is, then you can return early and not hide.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you could do it like this:

```
$("body").click(function() {
   if ($(".modal").is(":visible")) {
       $(".modal").hide();
   }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Using bootstrap 4, you can close modal when clicking outside by just doing this.

```
 $('.modal').click(function (e) {
    $('.modal').modal('toggle');
 });
```